# Не скролится сайт при нажатии на кнопку "продолжить покупки"

Tags: javascript

реализовала на Тильде в корзине кнопку "Продолжить покупки".
При нажатии на нее пользователь возвращается на главную, но сайт перестает скролится.
В чем может быть причина?

Вот сайт: https://geo-food.com/

Код кнопки:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.t706__sidebar-bottom').prepend("<button class='continue-btn'>ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ ПОКУПКИ</button>");
  $('.continue-btn').on('click touchend', function(){
    $('#rec529850416').hide();
    
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: при клике Добавить в корзину открывается окно и для ```body``` добавляется класс ```t706__body_cartsidebarshowed``` - ```overflow: hidden;```. А кнопка Продолжить покупки - этот класс не удаляет

Answer (score 0):

У вас на странице есть код, который закрывает корзину.
Нужно добавить условие которое будет удалять класс (.t706__body_cartsidebarshowed) при нажатии на кнопку.

Найдите в шаблоне код

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('.t706__sidebar-bottom').prepend("<button class='continue-btn'>ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ ПОКУПКИ</button>");
       $('.continue-btn').on('click touchend', function(){
        $('#rec529850416').hide();
      });
    });
```

Замените на:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.t706__sidebar-bottom').prepend("<button class='continue-btn'>ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ ПОКУПКИ</button>");
  $('.continue-btn').on('click touchend', function(){
    $('#rec529850416').hide();

    $('body').removeClass('t706__body_cartsidebarshowed');

  });
});
```

Comment: Благодарю))
Все получилось))